# Accepting an answer after cookie removal

Tags: support, accepted-answer, up-votes, cookies

I just found this unlikely situation.

I posed a question.

Subsequently I had to remove cookies from my browser.
Went back to accept the answer, but even though I was logged in the page thought that the question didn't belong to me - hence it wouldn't let me mark the answer as accepted.

Is there way recover from this situation so that the page knows the question is mine?

Of course I'm making the assumption that the problem arose because I had removed the cookies from my browser, perhaps something else was amiss?

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just log in again?

Comment: Well I was logged in. perhaps the log out, log in process would have solved it?